# how to validate local eth blockchain data

Tags: blockchain, etherscan

How can I verify if the data saved by a blockchain node is consistent with the data on the blockchain? Should I request both the local data and on-chain data for each block in order to verify if they are consistent?

Comment: How are you getting the local data? Are you using a client like geth? Geth in full/archive mode does the verification by itself. The fool proof of doing the verification is to execute every transaction after the genesis block, and validate the consensus rules of the block (PoW / PoS).